# How can I change api-platform {id} to a different name?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am using api-platform with Symfony 4.  It works fine, but I would like to change a GET url from:
`/booking/{id}` to `/booking/{bookingId}`

I'm using my own DTO object and custom data provider (not Doctrine ORM).

Here are the current `@ApiResource` and `@ApiProperty` definitions that work fine:

```
/**
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "path"="/booking/{id}",
 *          },
 *          "api_bookings_get_item"={
 *              "swagger_context"={
 *                  "operationId"="getBookingItem",
 *                  "summary"="Retrieves details on a booking",
 *                  "parameters"= {
 *                      {
 *                          "name"="id",
 *                          "description"="Booking ID",
 *                          "default"="15000",
 *                          "in"="path",
 *                          "required"=true,
 *                          "type"="string"
 *                      }
 *                  },
 *                  "responses"={
 *                      "200"={
 *                          "description"="Results retrieved"
 *                      },
 *                      "404"={
 *                          "description"="Booking not found"
 *                      }
 *                  }
 *              }
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={}
 * )
 */
final class Booking
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     *
     * @ApiProperty(
     *    identifier=true,
     *    attributes={
     *        "swagger_context"={
     *            "description"="Booking ID",
     *            "required"=true,
     *            "type"="string",
     *            "example"="123456"
     *        }
     *     }
     * }
     */
     public $id;

     // other variables

 }
```

However, if I change all the references from `'id'` to `'bookingId'` it stops working and I get a `404` error.  Here are the changes I made to the above code:

```
"path"="/booking/{bookingId}"

"name"="bookingId"

public $bookingId;
```

Is api-platform hard-coded to use `'id'` as an identifier?  Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

In Api-platform the id parameter is hardcoded:

```
namespace ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider;
private function extractIdentifiers(array $parameters, array $attributes)
    {
        if (isset($attributes['item_operation_name'])) {
            if (!isset($parameters['id'])) {
                throw new InvalidIdentifierException('Parameter "id" not found');
            }
```

but you can create your own operation and use the parameter name that you want there is a great example in docs [custom operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the apiResource identifier via:

```
     /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     */
    private $id;
```

and:

```
     /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     */
    private $uuid;
```

where uuid is the new identifier to be used in request URLs.

For reference: symfonycasts did an excellent tutorial here:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-extending/uuid-identifier